# In pytorch, what is difference between detach().requires_grad_(True) vs .cpu()?

Tags: pytorch

In pytorch, what is the difference between x.detach().requires_grad_(True) and x.cpu(), given x is a tensor?

Are they the same operations?

Answer (score 0):

1. `tensor.cpu()` returns a copy of this object in CPU memory, After that the computation of x will be done on the cpu.
2. `tensor.detach()` returns a new Tensor, detached from the current computation graph. The result will never require gradient.
3. `tensor.requires_grad_()` changes if autograd should record operations on this tensor: sets this tensor’s requires_grad attribute in-place. If you use `x.requires_grad_(True)`, which means the operations on x will be recorded and these can be used to calculate gradient.

Refer to [some results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAqUM.png), `tensor.requires_grad_()` and `tensor.detach()` do not change the device where the variable is located, which is different from `tensor.cpu()`.

According to [pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html?highlight=detach#torch.Tensor.detach), now in-place modifications on `tensor.detach()` like add_() is disallowed, which is shown in [some results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAqUM.png). But these operations on `tensor.cpu()` is allowed.

Comment: The usage of `x.detach().requires_grad_(True)` comes from the official pytorch website (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CTCLoss.html), also [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tensor-detach-method-in-python-pytorch/) says `detach` moves a tensor from GPU to CPU.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will edit my answer to improve it

Comment: Actually I still think `x.detach().requires_grad_(True)` is weird for me.

Comment: Maybe you're right. It's not very common.